# how to undo and redo chess moves using chessboard.js for analyze mode

Tags: javascript, chess, chessboard.js

I am using the `chess.js` and `chessboard.js` for my chess a project.

I just want to implement the undo and redo functionality of chess moves.

I am creating "Move Recorder" for chess moves using `chessboard.js`, through which users can undo and redo chess moves. User is playing from both sides to analyze chess puzzle.

Please let me know if any one can help on this.

Comment: only weak players take moves back, and only fools let opponents do so.

Comment: I have tried from "chessboard.js"

Answer (score 3):

Typically the game logic, validation and move history recording, *aren't* done with `chessboard.js` but with an engine, such as `chess.js`.

With an engine there might be an `undo()` or `takeback()` function, see the `chess.js` docs for an [example](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md#undo):

```
chess.move('e4');
chess.fen();
// -> 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq e3 0 1'

chess.undo();
// -> { color: 'w', from: 'e2', to: 'e4', flags: 'b', piece: 'p', san: 'e4' }
chess.fen();
// -> 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1'
```

There is also an open branch at `chess.js`, https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/pull/48

this code implements `next()` and `back()` functions into the engine, (and a `future` array for storing the history). These might be what you're looking for, because after you undo, you mention you want to **redo**.

This branch isn't merged, and I don't think it will be, but it's there to look at; basically just add these two functions:

```
back: function() {
  var moves = this.history();
  var tmp = new Chess();
  var previous = moves.length-future.length-1;
  for(var i=0;i<previous;i++) {
    tmp.move(moves[i]);
  }
  var previous_fen = tmp.fen();
  tmp.move(moves[previous]);
  future.push(tmp.fen());
  return previous_fen;
},

next: function() {
  return future.pop();
},
```

and an array

```
var future = [];
```

Then you can call `back()`, analyze the position, and then `next()` to return to the game state.

Answer (score 1):

Start here for the basic design.
[data structure used to implement UNDO and REDO option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701131/data-structure-used-to-implement-undo-and-redo-option)

And I presume there are methods in this framework to keep track of the commands you'll need for designated past actions.

Hope that helps!